# How to generate PDF in Google Drive based on specific cell values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I have been attempting to create a script to generate a PDF from specific values in a Google Spreadsheet. The Spreadsheet is populated from another spreadsheet, which populates from a Google Form.

Here is the [spreadsheet] containing the data to be displayed on the PDF.[1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGeFIpp3svlTXcIuxICUVEUhZw9tvYYayQxJKnTJASw/edit#gid=0)

I would like to automatically generate a PDF whenever the information in the spreadsheet is updated from the form.

The PDF would display two pieces of information from each row if that row meets the follow criteria. If the integer in the Quantity Needed is greater than or equal to 0, I would like the PDF to display the Item name and then the integer of Quantity needed for that row. The loop would continue until it reaches the last item.

I have tried to determine if a query is best to accomplish this or if getting the data into an array is better.

I have the following code to generate the PDF:

```js
function savePDFs() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var url = ss.getUrl();
  
  //remove the trailing 'edit' from the url
  url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');
  
  //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + //export as pdf
  //below parameters are optional...
  '&size=letter' + //paper size
  '&portrait=true' + //orientation, false for landscape
  '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide optional headers and footers
  '&gridlines=false' + //hide gridlines
  '&fzr=false' + //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId(); //the sheet's Id
  
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });
    
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');

  //from here you should be able to use and manipulate the blob to send and email or create a file per usual.
  //In this example, I save the pdf to drive
  
  DocsList.createFile(blob);
  //OR DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

I am having a difficult time understanding how to actually create a script to do the query or array and then print those results to a PDF.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This code will do it for you (there is a demo and more info [here](http://www.andrewroberts.net/2014/10/google-apps-script-create-pdf/)):

```
// Replace this with ID of your template document.
var TEMPLATE_ID = '';

// var TEMPLATE_ID = '1wtGEp27HNEVwImeh2as7bRNw-tO4HkwPGcAsTrSNTPc'; // Demo template
// Demo script - http://bit.ly/createPDF

/**
 * Eventhandler for spreadsheet opening - add a menu.
 */

function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('Create PDF')
    .addItem('Create PDF', 'createPdf')
    .addToUi();

} // onOpen()

/**  
 * Take the fields from the active row in the active sheet
 * and, using a Google Doc template, create a PDF doc with these
 * fields replacing the keys in the template. The keys are identified
 * by having a % either side, e.g. %Name%.
 *
 * @return {Object} the completed PDF file
 */

function createPdf() {

  if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs');
    return;
  }

  // Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

  var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
      copyId = copyFile.getId(),
      copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
      copyBody = copyDoc.getBody(),
      activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
      activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(),
      activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      columnIndex = 0,
      pdfFile;

  // Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values

  for (;columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {

    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%', 
                         activeRow[0][columnIndex]);                         
  }

  // Create the PDF file and delete the doc copy

  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs("application/pdf"));  

  copyFile.setTrashed(true);

  return pdfFile;

} // createPdf()
```